# Determine which substring from array is present in given string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a array of few string

For ex: `["hello", "World", "nice"]`

Now i have a long url string with special string.

I want to find out which string from above array is present in my url string using Ruby and return that string.

Comment: Use `each` and check to see if it's in the URL. What's the specific issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to avoid each and want some useful regex which can give me that substring in less time.

Comment: And you've determined this is a relevant performance bottleneck in your system??? So join them together with a `|` and do a regex. Then do the relevant performance tests. Then ponder if the time you wasted was actually worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
words.find { |w| url[w] }
```

Example:

```
 ["hello", "World", "nice"].find { |w| "this is nice"[w] }
 # => "nice"
```

Comment: +1, I came here to post this! To add to your answer, note that `find`/`detect` will return the first match only. The methods `find_all`/`select` are available if one needs all the values that match.